# How can I install software on a different drive to avoid running out of space in the root partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

My root partition is small but I have an empty Linux file system in which I want to install new software so that my root partition does not run out of space.

How can I set this up?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of gparted and upload it to imjur.com and the add the link to your question? It is not possible to move programs easily. If you edit your question and explain the problem better, we may suggest a different solution.

Comment: You don't. What you do is add empty space to your root. The advice is 10Gb/25Gb for / depending on use-case, so what did you set it to?

Comment: What size is your root partition? It may be fine as it is. Even 20G seems sufficient in general.

One option is to expand your root partition. Is that possible?

I've never done it, but I've seen instructions on line for moving a root partition.